# C - Increment and decrement pointer, then retrieve value

Tags: c, pointers

The following code outputs y as a massive integer, not `15`. I don't understand why. I know the `--` and `++` operators come before the `*` operator, so it should work.

What the follwing code is trying to say.

```
/*
Create a variable, set to 15.
Create a pointer to that variable.
Increment the pointer, into undefined memory space.
Decrement the pointer back where it was,
then return the value of what is there,
and save it into the  variable y.
Print y.    
*/

int main()
{
    int x = 15;
    int *test = &x;
    test++;
    int y = *test--;
    printf("%d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

If instead, I change the code to the following:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 15;
    int *test = &x;
    test++;
    test--;
    printf("%d\n", *test);

    return 0;
}
```

That code outputs `15`. Why?

Comment: Because `test--` evaluates to the undecremented value, `*test--` dereferences the pointer that points into la-la-land.  If you used `*--test`, then it would be OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But the when the program encounters `*test--`, it first does `test--` then it does `*test`, surely? I read that `--` has presidence over `*`. If that's not the case, what exactly is happening in the line `*test--` in detail?

Comment: @Hatefiend that's why `y` will be an address of `x` minus sizeof(int), approximated.

Comment: Yes, in `*test--`, the `test--` is evaluated first. It evaluates to the old value of `test` and decrements the variable as a side-effect.  Then the `*` uses the value 'returned' by `test--` (which is still the undecremented value) and uses that. If you want to do the decrement before the dereference and you want to use the decremented pointer, you must write it `*--test`. The values returned by `x++` and `++x` are different; ditto with `x--` and `--x`. It is crucial that you recognize this. Only when written standalone (as an entire statement such as `…; test--; …`) is the net result the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is between `x++` and `++x`, post- and pre-increment of a pointer.

- When `++` is after `x`, the old value is used prior to the increment
- When `++` is before `x`, the new value is used after the increment.

This will work:

```
int y = *(--test);
```

Although parentheses are not necessary, it is a good idea to use them for clarity.

Comment: Interesting. What if I wanted to increment the *value* of wherever the pointer is pointing to? for example: `int x = 15;` `int *y = &x;` `(*y)++;` `printf("%d\n", *y); // Expected print: 16`

Comment: @Hatefiend Yes, use parentheses to tell the compiler what to increment, the pointer or the thing that the pointer is pointing to.